# Custom Css Grid with Vanilla Css (No Framework)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div element that is split in half and in one of the halfs, have 4 equal square boxes.

So far I think I have the initial set up but when I try to produce the 4 squares within one of the halfs one overflows past the other leaving both halfs not equal. I hope the code snippet might help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Example</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <style>    
      *, *:after, *:before {
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          background: gray;
          min-width: 100%;
      }
      .container {
   min-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 4px ;

   }

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width:inherit
  }


/* GRID SYSTEM */
.row::after {
 content: '';
 clear: both;
 display: block;

 }
  @media only screen
    and (min-width : 300px)
      and (max-width : 640px) {

      .col { float: left;}
   .col { float: left;}
  .mobile-not {

  display:none;
  }
  }

  @media only screen
    and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col { float: left;}
 .col-6-md { width: 50%; }
  }



 @media only screen
  and (min-width : 1224px) {

 .col-1 { width: 8.33%; }
.col-2 { width: 16.66%; }
.col-2-sm {width: inherit; }
.col-3 { width: 25%; }
.col-4 { width: 33.33%; }
.col-5 { width: 41.66%; }
.col-6 { width: 50%; }
.col-6-md {
  display:block;
  width: inherit;
  }
.col-7 { width: 58.33%; }
.col-8 { width: 66.66%; }
.col-9 { width: 75%; }
.col-10 { width: 83.33%; }
.col-11 { width: 91.66%; }
.col-12 { width: 100%; }
 }

 img {
 width: 100%;
 }


 .text-demo {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  }
 .text-prop {
 padding-right: 20px;
 color:white;
 text-align: right;
 width:100%;

}

 </style>


   </head>
   <body>


 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6">
    <a href="/search/">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xVYh_uJU1fipLAg85BABZvd5rmSTCg-lSFkZR78jP9lCNxjVRHF8dcIkRE_sGh7ReMWs0xo0azaV-nnCsZ-BVbPBVEjZuVi6uojDNHaDlohDCNM2hGL02nASyMhhdWH5yZ6ZjKF2di8IC6HCkDS-VZ5UBb4eryKcmtbKvpDRm7q-knmu_C9GQx3CsNjQIkZhpmoI6asAlrs_DkJK2hgLN_n-lXFBhLDEQnnYMWR1iYLa3yePtSPVHSzzKOODpNPQqZM9oVtNRizEIysesic__qzrHW0bSmEANsnhutwK--2Cs4jc96isl0XQdKfsqTHzcG_Nc5g2-gIegFHnDWYxsh-KgqLtizc4VaBB2oe1BhUN98pIblCkSVgr88PNSPzeqdF6Dz1fjxCqbD1uvuhfPlhiDmcrmLFyf9fzqYzQtOFLyZuojLohGjivsMYhUkSdghen7XkkdvJx-6lK9baVw4kHXp7M1ZbufApnT8wb1PPBmA8Y1TqkeRQkIfBnEbX5G6VWRNiq0AIOWwkvJSwxGLlwL7Kuh7p77JbTqyn-0w1ydDq80bmFKtvnvnf2AQEvmuTFdgSiFAMWJbYlb5o8_nnuGvATqmCd57DanPW8mOsrULpfaTHi=w468-h379-no">
          </a>
     </div>


    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="col-2-sm">
<a href="/search/">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xVYh_uJU1fipLAg85BABZvd5rmSTCg-lSFkZR78jP9lCNxjVRHF8dcIkRE_sGh7ReMWs0xo0azaV-nnCsZ-BVbPBVEjZuVi6uojDNHaDlohDCNM2hGL02nASyMhhdWH5yZ6ZjKF2di8IC6HCkDS-VZ5UBb4eryKcmtbKvpDRm7q-knmu_C9GQx3CsNjQIkZhpmoI6asAlrs_DkJK2hgLN_n-lXFBhLDEQnnYMWR1iYLa3yePtSPVHSzzKOODpNPQqZM9oVtNRizEIysesic__qzrHW0bSmEANsnhutwK--2Cs4jc96isl0XQdKfsqTHzcG_Nc5g2-gIegFHnDWYxsh-KgqLtizc4VaBB2oe1BhUN98pIblCkSVgr88PNSPzeqdF6Dz1fjxCqbD1uvuhfPlhiDmcrmLFyf9fzqYzQtOFLyZuojLohGjivsMYhUkSdghen7XkkdvJx-6lK9baVw4kHXp7M1ZbufApnT8wb1PPBmA8Y1TqkeRQkIfBnEbX5G6VWRNiq0AIOWwkvJSwxGLlwL7Kuh7p77JbTqyn-0w1ydDq80bmFKtvnvnf2AQEvmuTFdgSiFAMWJbYlb5o8_nnuGvATqmCd57DanPW8mOsrULpfaTHi=w468-h379-no">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2-sm mobile-not">
           <div class="text-demo">
          <div class="text-prop">
        <br>
        <font size="3.5"> <strong>Wcsho </strong> </font><br>
        <font size="6"> <strong>Demo Site </strong><br></font><br>


        <font size="3"> SALES: 888-888-1234<br>
        SERVICE: 888-888-1234<br>
      Custom: 888-888-1234<br>
      </font>
                    <br>
        <font size="2">
        <a href="/hours-and-directions/">
            918 greenville Rd,<br> uk
        </a>
        </font>
        <br><br>
            </div>

        <br>
      </div>


          </div>
            <br style="clear:both" />
            <div class="col-2-sm">
            <a href="/search/">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xVYh_uJU1fipLAg85BABZvd5rmSTCg-lSFkZR78jP9lCNxjVRHF8dcIkRE_sGh7ReMWs0xo0azaV-nnCsZ-BVbPBVEjZuVi6uojDNHaDlohDCNM2hGL02nASyMhhdWH5yZ6ZjKF2di8IC6HCkDS-VZ5UBb4eryKcmtbKvpDRm7q-knmu_C9GQx3CsNjQIkZhpmoI6asAlrs_DkJK2hgLN_n-lXFBhLDEQnnYMWR1iYLa3yePtSPVHSzzKOODpNPQqZM9oVtNRizEIysesic__qzrHW0bSmEANsnhutwK--2Cs4jc96isl0XQdKfsqTHzcG_Nc5g2-gIegFHnDWYxsh-KgqLtizc4VaBB2oe1BhUN98pIblCkSVgr88PNSPzeqdF6Dz1fjxCqbD1uvuhfPlhiDmcrmLFyf9fzqYzQtOFLyZuojLohGjivsMYhUkSdghen7XkkdvJx-6lK9baVw4kHXp7M1ZbufApnT8wb1PPBmA8Y1TqkeRQkIfBnEbX5G6VWRNiq0AIOWwkvJSwxGLlwL7Kuh7p77JbTqyn-0w1ydDq80bmFKtvnvnf2AQEvmuTFdgSiFAMWJbYlb5o8_nnuGvATqmCd57DanPW8mOsrULpfaTHi=w468-h379-no">
          </a>

      </div>

      <div class="col-2-sm">
            <a href="/search/">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xVYh_uJU1fipLAg85BABZvd5rmSTCg-lSFkZR78jP9lCNxjVRHF8dcIkRE_sGh7ReMWs0xo0azaV-nnCsZ-BVbPBVEjZuVi6uojDNHaDlohDCNM2hGL02nASyMhhdWH5yZ6ZjKF2di8IC6HCkDS-VZ5UBb4eryKcmtbKvpDRm7q-knmu_C9GQx3CsNjQIkZhpmoI6asAlrs_DkJK2hgLN_n-lXFBhLDEQnnYMWR1iYLa3yePtSPVHSzzKOODpNPQqZM9oVtNRizEIysesic__qzrHW0bSmEANsnhutwK--2Cs4jc96isl0XQdKfsqTHzcG_Nc5g2-gIegFHnDWYxsh-KgqLtizc4VaBB2oe1BhUN98pIblCkSVgr88PNSPzeqdF6Dz1fjxCqbD1uvuhfPlhiDmcrmLFyf9fzqYzQtOFLyZuojLohGjivsMYhUkSdghen7XkkdvJx-6lK9baVw4kHXp7M1ZbufApnT8wb1PPBmA8Y1TqkeRQkIfBnEbX5G6VWRNiq0AIOWwkvJSwxGLlwL7Kuh7p77JbTqyn-0w1ydDq80bmFKtvnvnf2AQEvmuTFdgSiFAMWJbYlb5o8_nnuGvATqmCd57DanPW8mOsrULpfaTHi=w468-h379-no">
          </a>
      </div>



     </div>


     </div>

     </div>


     </body>

      </html>
```

Any help would be appreciative, I can't figure out how to get everything to fit equally.

Comment: wouldn't you just set them to be { width:25% } or use flexbox?

Comment: Tried setting the width to 25%, It doesn't keep the even squares like the current code does, Can you provide an example of how I would try it with flexbox?

Comment: Sure, just download http://materializecss.com/ you'll find examples in there of exactly that. Flex columns stretch to fit evenly, if you want more control over them, try the max-width property.

Comment: I was attempting to solve the issue without any css framework.

Comment: What I have currently seems to work it's just not being displayed equally, idk if you have time but you could pop the code snip into a html file and sort of see what I mean.

Comment: I'm not saying use a css framework, I'm saying reference the the code in a css framework to see how it's done.

Comment: And no, sorry - You could set-up a js-fiddle or codepen. This is a place to get advice on how to do things - not a place to get work done for free.

Comment: Work done for free? clearly the whole example was done, all you had to say was you didn't want to set up a code pen. Your comments have been useless because you haven't offered any advice toward the question. You should just reference the specific section instead of an entire framework. Again it's have been no help, the code snippet was provided so your not doing any work for me.

Comment: And never asked you to complete anything so your comment really sounded stupid

Comment: Also, think about what you're saying before you make a comment. Technically this question is using the site correctly. You present your problem with your code example. Your answers were useless, along with your egotistic comment, maybe learn how to answer a stack question correctly? Or just write it down to yourself next time. Thanks

Comment: Now you're mad? Look, how would you feel if someone asked you "How doI get to the bakery?" and they said "Two blocks down and turn left". Then they said "No, that's not how I want to get to the bakery, why don't you drive me there and I'll tell you where to go". Be grateful for what you get. I'm not here to give you a fish, I'd rather teach you to fish - know what I mean? But thanks. And sorry for the 'useless' answers.

Comment: Also, I pointed you to materialize css grid because by looking at the source of it, you're likely to find other good ideas that you can implement in your project. Sorry I offended you.

Comment: It was offensive, not angry, and I don't see how your example relates. You didn't give any directions you mentioned that flex was a part of css framework and listed the framework not anything specific to my issue did you even look at the code? I would agree if my question was more opinion based but it's not.  I am grateful for any help I get but I'm not grateful for comments that have nothing to do with the topic and also disrespectful.

Comment: You treated my question like I'm a nuub which is insulting. You clearly said "I won't do the work for you ". I got offended because in what comment did I ask that from you. The only thing I offered was for you to insert the code in a Html document if you wanted to see visually the issue I am talking about. I don't know how you get "Do work" from that. Smh my responses is not out of anger I'm just asking for you to consider your responses before you post because you never who you are offending.

Comment: you offered materialize css without a specific section why would I need materialize? wouldn't I be able to do the same thing with other css frameworks like Bootstrap? That's why I said your comment and suggestions were useless. It wasn't a specific example or any specific help unlike the accepted answer, and then you have the nerve to say I'm asking you to do work? If anything the accepted answer went above and beyond. I would see if you did something like that and I asked even further but I didn't and you definitely didn't. So cheers bro no hard feelings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using flexbox with pure CSS.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row{
  display: flex;
}
.col{
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.square{
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.square:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col row">
    <div class="col square"></div>
    <div class="col square"></div>
    <div class="col square"></div>
    <div class="col square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!